# Node Args for File Extension RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'd like to search a directory for a specific filetype using node.js.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = process.argv[2]; // directory
var ext = process.argv[3]; // file extension to search for

fs.readdir( dir, function(err, list) {
    if(err)
        throw err;

    // build regex search
    var re = new RegExp("^.*\." + ext + "$");

    // print if specific extension found
    list.forEach( function(item) {
    if( re.test(item) ) 
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

And here's the execution:

```
  node readDir.js ./ js
```

But I'm getting result for a file with no extension. Console output:

```
01-express.js
hihihijs
myprogram.js
readDir.js
readFileAsync.js
readFileSync.js
```

Is my regular expression wrong? In this case it would be ^.*.js$

Comment: when you declare a regex object with new you should double escape backslashes. try `RegExp("^.*\\." + ext + "$");`

Comment: that's it! thank you! can i vote your comment as the correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a regex object with new you should escape backslashes.

Try `var re = new RegExp("^.*\\." + ext + "$");`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)